# C++ cancelling a pthread using a secondary thread stuck in function call

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I'm having trouble instituting a timeout in one of my `pthreads`. I've simplified my code here and I've isolated the issue to be the CNF algorithm I'm running in the thread.

```
int main(){
  pthread_t t1;
  pthread_t t2;
  pthread_t t3; //Running multiple threads, the others work fine and do not require a timeout.

  pthread_create(&t1, nullptr, thread1, &args);
  pthread_join(t1, nullptr);

  std::cout << "Thread should exit and print this\n"; //This line never prints since from what I've figured to be a lack of cancellation points in the actual function running in the thread.

  return  0;
}

void* to(void* args) {
    int timeout{120};
    int count{0};
    while(count < timeout){
        sleep(1);
        count++;
    }
    std::cout << "Killing main thread" << std::endl;
    pthread_cancel(*(pthread_t *)args);
}

void *thread1 (void *arguments){
  //Create the timeout thread within the CNF thread to wait 2 minutes and then exit this whole thread
  pthread_t time;
  pthread_t cnf = pthread_self();
  pthread_create(&time, nullptr, &timeout, &cnf);

  //This part runs and prints that the thread has started
  std::cout << "CNF running\n"; 
  auto *args = (struct thread_args *) arguments;

  int start = args->vertices;
  int end = 1;

  while (start >= end) {
     //This is where the issue lies 
     cover = find_vertex_cover(args->vertices, start, args->edges_a, args->edges_b); 

    start--;
  }

  pthread_cancel(time); //If the algorithm executes in the required time then the timeout is not needed and that thread is cancelled. 
  std::cout << "CNF END\n";
  return nullptr;
}
```

I tried commenting out the `find_vertex_cover` function and add an `infinite loop` and I was able to create a `timeout` and end the thread that way. The function is actually working the exact way it should. It should take forever to run under the conditions I'm running it at and therefore I need a timeout.

```
//This was a test thread function that I used to validate that implementing the timeout using `pthread_cancel()` this way works. The thread will exit once the timeout is reached.

void *thread1 (void *args) {
    pthread_t x1;
    pthread_t x2 = pthread_self();
    pthread_create(&x1, nullptr, to, &x2);

    /*
    for (int i = 0;i<100; i++){
        sleep(1);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    */
}
```

Using this function I was able to validate that my timeout thread approach worked. The issue is when I actually run the CNF algorithm (using Minisat under the hood) once `find_vertex_cover` runs, there is no way to end the thread. The algorithm is expected to fail in the situation I'm implementing which is why a timeout is being implemented.

I've read up on using `pthread_cancel()` and while it isn't a great way it's the only way I could implement a timeout.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Your formatting is pretty messed up, please fix that. Also, check the tags that you applied and whether their description actually fits. Also, make sure you include a [mcve] in your question. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Where is the function `timeout` defined in your code?  Or has it been misnamed `to`? Also note that the 'cancelability' of a thread depends on both its [cancel state and type](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setcancelstate.3.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read up on using pthread_cancel() and while it isn't a great way [..]

That's right. `pthread_cancel` should be avoided. It's *especially* bad for use in C++ as it's incompatible with exception handling. You should use `std::thread` and for thread termination, you can possibly use  conditional variable or a atomic variable that terminates the "infinite loop" when set.

That aside, cancellation via `pthread_cancel` depends on two things: 1) cancellation state 2) cancellation type.

Default cancellation state is *enabled*. But the default cancellation type is *deferred*  - meaning the cancellation request will be delivered only at the next cancellation point. I suspect there's any cancellation points in `find_vertex_cover`. So you could set the cancellation type to `asynchronous` via the call:

```
pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
```

from the thread(s) you want to be able to cancel immediately.

But again, I suggest to not go for `pthread_cancel` approach at all and instead rewrite the "cancel" logic so that it doesn't involve `pthread_cancel`.

Comment: Setting *state* enables cancellation. But *when* it happens is controlled via *type* (which is "deferred" by default). That's why you need to set both. Btw, cancellation state is `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE` by default (so you don't need to set this).